# Uninstalling using setup.exe

Tags: visual-studio-2010, outlook, windows-installer, command-prompt, office-addins

I'm not sure if the tags are appropriate, I added them as they deal with my specific situation.

I created an Outlook Add-In. To install it I created a Setup Project. The setup project creates a .msi and a setup.exe. I use the setup.exe to install the .msi. Done. That works great. I can run the setup.exe from the command prompt and install it silently like so "setup.exe /quiet". That works. Now, I'm trying to figure out how to uninstall it silently as well using the command line.

If I try "setup.exe /x" it just brings up a window of the available commands (/x being one of them). This happens as well if I try "setup.exe /x {product key}" or "setup.exe /x //".

If I try "setup.exe /uninstall" i get a message saying:

> This patch package could not be opened. Verify that the patch package exists and that you can access it, or contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer patch package.

If I try "setup.exe /uninstall {product key}" i get:

> The patch is not applied to this product.

The only I've been able to uninstall has been through double clicking the setup.exe and clicking "Remove Product" or through the Program and Features window.

The reason for this is if I update the setup project version and install the new version it will remove the old version, but when I run Outlook the new version of the addin is inactive. This doesn't happen on a fresh install. I wanted to write a batch file that will uninstall the old addin and then install the new one.

I don't know if there is a better way of getting the addin inside of Outlook, the only way in the tutorial mentioned was windows installer. The addin is going inside Outlook 2013 if that matters.

If you need any more info let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make such a call: `msiexec.exe /x {..<your MSI product code>..}`

Read more about the Windows Installer service: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759262(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: This did work. For some reason, until I saw your answer I always thought that when people said "msiexce.exe" they meant the .msi that was created by the setup project. It is not, it's found here for anyone else wondering: `C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe`. Thanks!

Comment: The MSI is just a simple database storing information about what to install. The Windows Installer service (msiexec.exe) from the OS handles the installation, based on the instructions read from the MSI package.